# Why WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class is not replaced by openrewrite while upgrading to spring boot 3.1

Tags: openrewrite

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated of course and I know what to use instead of it. But my question is 'was the replacement not taken care in the recipe'

Similarly I see that OrderImpl class from hibernate is deprecated and was not taken care by recipe.

Comment: What recipe did you run? And what version of OpenRewrite did you use? How did you configure OpenRewrite? All of these might factor in; without these details it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: We do have a recipe to replace WebMvcConfigurerAdapter specifically: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/framework/migratewebmvcconfigureradapter, which is also included with larger migrations such as this one to Spring Boot 3.1: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_1

Comment: I used this documentation https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_1.   And I upgraded from spring boot 2.5 to 2.7 first and then from 2.7 to 3.1 , all using open rewrite

Comment: I used the Maven plugin and ran the command mvn rewrite:run

Comment: We've had a couple of fixes related to spring security the past couple of weeks, which we've just released now. You'll want to try again with rewrite-spring 5.0.8 or higher

Comment: Curious to hear your issues with hibernate too.. feel free to log an issue on GitHub, that's the easiest way for us to keep track and follow up.

Answer (score 1):

here's a direct link to the recipe that should create the required code changes: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/framework/migratewebmvcconfigureradapter

It should also run as part of the Spring Boot 3 migration, which includes migrations to newer versions of Spring Security: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_1

To help debug your issue it would be good to know what [versions of the Maven plugin](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/releases) and [rewrite-spring](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/releases) you used. We just did a new release of both, which might already resolve your issues. If not, please [log an issue](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/issues) with more details.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I researched this tool, its having a simple approach of partially updating the selected incompatibilities and not matured enough to use it in production